# Chrome Resizing Navigation Menus

Tags: html, google-chrome, resize

So my problem is that for some reason on one page of a website I've been fiddling with, the two navigation bars that I have (Top and Sidebar Navigation) are for no apparent reason scaled down in the Google Chrome browser, their behavior is entirely normal in both iE and Firefox. The bar's remain completely functional, but are simply scaled down perhaps to 66% of the intended size.

Here is the code for the page in question: http://pastebin.com/uvrPR1JW

Here is the code for a similar, but functioning page for reference: http://pastebin.com/5dAMREfC

They're running off the same style sheet so the issue is likely in the HTML, however the style sheet is linked in the comment section for reference. If anyone spots any reason why it would be doing anything like this it'd be great to know. And I apologize for the messy code, as I said I'm just playing around with it.

Update:
You may notice that my code includes at least one flexbox, here is question posted by another user that may be related but I can't make heads or tails of it: [Chrome shrinks figure elements as they are added to a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585053/chrome-shrinks-figure-elements-as-they-are-added-to-a-flexbox)

Update: Doesn't seem to be a problem with the flexbox, the issue still exists even when I remove all content except the top header.

Comment: Have you ran it through the w3 validator? It might tell you the issue

Comment: I have in fact, it arrives at no conclusion other than it doesn't like the way I have my sidebar setup.

Comment: Can;t find CSS. Please provide CSS for the same.

Comment: Here's a pastebin link to the stylesheet for you guys: http://pastebin.com/8NmRjGr3

Comment: @CodeRomeos Sorry forgot to tag you in the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's the setup of your navbar, how you have an image and you just change the position of it on hover. Chrome has a weird feature where it moves things around when there is images so I would suggest looking up how to make a proper navigation bar (It's pretty easy).

Comment: I would agree with you there, although I disagree with your analysis of a "Proper" nav bar, mine is most certainly proper, just highly technical. However upon removal of all navigation aspects the header is still incorrectly sized.